# Python OSError: Bad address when reading from large file

Tags: python, io, centos

I am observing a "Bad address" `OSError` when reading from a file handle created using the `with` syntax in Python 3.

The file in question is 39G, but I should have enough RAM available to read the whole file. The error message leads me to believe I am hitting some kind of OS restriction; I am running CentOS 6.9.  Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this behavior?

The file is perfectly readable outside of python, e.g. in bash with `head` or `vim`.

Simplified code sample producing the error is shown below:

```
In [2]: with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") as infile:
   ...:     infile.read()
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3f216811bec7> in <module>()
  1 with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") as infile:
----> 2     infile.read()
  3 

OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

Comment: You are doing this in iPython, so it tries not only to read 39GB, but also to print them. That may be related to the problem and it may in fact require a significant overhead on required memory. Anyway, you should probably not read the whole file of this size into memory at once even if you do have enough RAM for that...

Comment: The obvious thing to do here is to `mmap` the file instead of `read` it (although this means you have `bytes` rather than `str`), which is what tools like `grep` do, or process it iteratively instead of all at once, which is what tools like `head` do.

Comment: Also, how much memory do you have? To read a 39GB UTF-8 textfile that's mostly ASCII, but has a few astral characters in it, requires about 156GB for the final string.

Comment: Anyway, it's possible that you _can_ read the whole file into memory, but you _can't_ do it all in one `read()`. Especially if you're using Python 2.x, but maybe even with 3.x. For example, your Python may be ultimately using the older `read` call that uses a 32-bit size and fails if it's more than `1<<31`.

Comment: @zvone, the issue is that I'm using another IO library that is, ultimately, calling `read()` on the file handle, so while I would love to read in chunks at a time that will complicate the IO issue substantively.

Comment: @abarnert, this is useful info; I was only reserving RAM space of 64G, I will see if things turn out differently with 200GB+ available.  If increasing the memory limit doesn't help here, I think the obvious thing is probably to write my own IO code and read it iteratively/memmap it.

Comment: @Suriname0 Well, if you have a huge file, too big to load at once, and you are using a library which needs to read the whole file at once, you may in the end have to acknowledge that this library does not fit your needs :\

Comment: I think the issue was what abarnert identified: needing a larger memory cap.  I also switched to a batch reading + in-memory concatenation approach, and that's working better. It's not directly relevant to this issue, but I'll also note that I ran into the following bug which I wasn't aware of: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1907