# Does gzip library in python attempt to open entire file in memory?

Tags: python

```
with gzip.open("/tar/access.tar.gz", 'rb') as f_in:
    with open("/tar/access.tar", 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

My input file is 150GB. I raised my server to 432GB of ram once I realized it was running out of memory at 50GB when attempting to do this. Does gzip attempt to open  the entire file in memory first? Why is 432GB not enough?

The exact error is `OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address: '/tar/access.tar.gz'` But this is thrown when there is a memory error.

Stack trace :

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py in open(filename, mode, compresslevel, encoding, errors, newline)
     51     gz_mode = mode.replace("t", "")
     52     if isinstance(filename, (str, bytes)):
---> 53         binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
     54     elif hasattr(filename, "read") or hasattr(filename, "write"):
     55         binary_file = GzipFile(None, gz_mode, compresslevel, filename)

/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py in __init__(self, filename, mode, compresslevel, fileobj, mtime)
    161             mode += 'b'
    162         if fileobj is None:
--> 163             fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
    164         if filename is None:
    165             filename = getattr(fileobj, 'name', '')

OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address: '/tar/access.tar.gz'
```

For anyone that doesn't believe this is a memory issue and thinks the file doesn't exist, based on the poorly worded error message, with 16gb it fails within seconds, with 64GB it lasts just under a minute, and with 432GB it lasts 5 minutes before failing.

And what is the solution to uncompress a gzip file without it all going to memory?

Related question - [Python OSError: Bad address when reading from large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634054/python-oserror-bad-address-when-reading-from-large-file)

Also fails with the following:

```
with gzip.open("/dbfs/tmp/tar/access.tar.gz", 'rb') as f_in:
    print("here")
```

Comment: `/tar/access.tar.gz` looks like your input is a tape.

Comment: The linked related question makes much more sense -- that one's actually *reading* the file, after all. Here, the stack trace is showing the failure coming from `open()` itself, implying that we don't even get to the `read()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  It is failing on this line `with gzip.open("/dbfs/tmp/tar/access.tar.gz", 'rb') as f_in:`  as I removed other code and put a simple print statement in the block and it is failing with the same error.

Comment: Maybe there's something about this particular file? Have you tried it with any others?

Comment: It *would* be interesting to know what the filesystem is.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, worked perfectly fine on smaller files.  Attempting solution provided by Jean below.

Comment: you could copy the file on a standard disk and try from here, see if it's the same.

Comment: Frankly, just using `strace` or [`sysdig`](https://sysdig.org/) to know what layer the error  is at is coming from would be helpful. If it's a FUSE-based filesystem driver and not your Python program at all that's running out of memory, that's a critical detail.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am running this on Databricks, and there provided temporary disk space.  I don't have anyway to know what the storage type is.

Comment: This is apparently a bug in Python 3.5: see https://bugs.python.org/issue25626

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't have access to the actual system, I am running this on a Databricks cluster.

Comment: If you can run code on it, it's probably still possible to do at least a bit of introspection; see f/e [determining the filesystem type from a path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283882/determining-the-filesystem-type-from-a-path-in-python)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `[sdiskpart(device='/dev/sdc', mountpoint='/mnt/readonly', fstype='ext4', opts='ro,relatime,data=ordered'),
 sdiskpart(device='/dev/mapper/vg-lv', mountpoint='/local_disk0', fstype='ext4', opts='rw,relatime,data=ordered')]`

Comment: ...that tells us about `/mnt/readonly` and `/local_disk0`; unfortunately, it doesn't tell us about `/dbfs`.

Comment: When I do `get_fs_type("/mnt/readonly")` I get `ext4` when I do `get_fs_type("/dbfs")` I get empty. But when I do `os.listdir("/dbfs")` it correctly lists the directories in it, so it clearly exists. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @CharlesDuffy After doing some digging, it seems as though the `/dbfs` path is a mounted s3 path, according to this https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html

Comment: If the software doing that mount doesn't support files larger than RAM, well, there's your issue.

Comment: jasonharper reported that as a python 3.5 bug. It's fixed, so upgrading to python 3.7 should fix the issue

Comment: I believe `tarfile` library could be a reasonable alternative for `gzip`. As implemented [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-uncompress-a-tar-gz-file-using-python/).